Adding a confounder `Factor` vs. subtracting within-level mean
In order to account for a known confounder, one can add an additional factor (that describes the confounding effect) in linear regression.
For example in R, we could have:
model <- lm(response ~ predictor + confounder, data = data)

Here, response is a Covariate (i.e., continuous value), while predictor and confounder are Factors.
My understanding is that using the above formula, the estimated response will be adjusted by the mean of samples within confounder levels (as beautifully explained in Law et al., see Figure.1).
Now, I wonder about the difference between the above modeling approach vs. subtracting the mean of response in samples within each confounder level before fitting the model. I assume that we should end up with the coefficient for predictor.
What would be the drawback of this approach?
To motivate why this is important:
I am modeling a dataset where I know a confounder exists. But, I also know that samples within each level of the confounder could be outliers. Therefore, I prefer to adjust the response of the samples by their Median instead of their Mean (that is done in Linear Regression, as explained above) and then remove the confounder from the formula.
I am wondering if I am missing something if I follow this approach?
Update:
It may help if I provide an actual example:
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
    response=rep(c(0, 5, 10, 15), each=5) + rnorm(20, 0, 0.01),
    predictor=rep(c(0, 1), each=10),
    confounder=rep(c(0, 1, 0, 1), each=5)
)
print(df)

The data looks like this:
       response predictor confounder
1   0.013709584         0          0
2  -0.005646982         0          0
3   0.003631284         0          0
4   0.006328626         0          0
5   0.004042683         0          0
6   4.998938755         0          1
7   5.015115220         0          1
8   4.999053410         0          1
9   5.020184237         0          1
10  4.999372859         0          1
11 10.013048697         1          0
12 10.022866454         1          0
13  9.986111393         1          0
14  9.997212112         1          0
15  9.998666787         1          0
16 15.006359504         1          1
17 14.997157471         1          1
18 14.973435446         1          1
19 14.975595331         1          1
20 15.013201133         1          1

Now we can model the response by:
model <- lm(response ~ predictor + confounder, data = df)
print(summary(model))

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ predictor + confounder, data = df)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.022852 -0.004370 -0.002504  0.010484  0.022423 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.007551   0.005089    1.484    0.156    
predictor   9.992892   0.005876 1700.650   <2e-16 ***
confounder  4.995844   0.005876  850.223   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01314 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.808e+06 on 2 and 17 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Alternatively, I am thinking of removing the confounder effect by:
is_1 <- df$confounder == 1
diff <- mean(df[is_1, "response"]) - mean(df[!is_1, "response"])
df[is_1, "response"] = df[is_1, "response"] - diff
model <- lm(response ~ predictor, data = df)
print(summary(model))

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ predictor, data = df)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.022852 -0.004370 -0.002504  0.010484  0.022423 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.007551   0.004038    1.87   0.0778 .  
predictor   9.992892   0.005710 1749.95   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01277 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 3.062e+06 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Notice that we end up with identical coefficients for Intercept and predictor. But, indeed as @BenP pointed out, we will estimate degrees of freedom as 18, instead of 17 and also the Standard Errors would change. On the other hand, this approach allowes me to remove Median instead of Mean when I am dealing with noisy samples. So, I lose accuracy of p-values but then I gain robustness. I wonder if someone could provide a bit more intuitive explanation of what where this could go very wrong if I follow this approach (and remove the Median when dealing with noisy samples).
Update 2:
As requested, here is a more extensive picture of what I am dealing with.
We are investigating several drugs' effects after stimulating a cell line with a particular nutrition. We are measuring the cell's entire protein profile for this. The cells are stimulated (and drug treated) for 2 hours, or 24 hours. We do two replicates (they are the similarly colored markers, see below). Finally, we already know that the duration of treatment is a confounder. A very small portion of the results, for only a single protein is shown below:

In the plot above, you can see:

Treatment duration shown using circle and trinagle.

A longer treatment time (i.e., 24h) changes the activity of the protein. This is very clear in the control setting, where even non-stimulated cells (hollow markers) show change of activity.

Stimulation increaes activity of the protein (compare hollow vs. filled in markers)

Higher doses of the drug treatment (see differently colored markers) have stronger effect.

Note that this is a single protein. We are measureing about 1000 proteins.

We are asking several quentions from this datasset:



Which proteins show reaction to Stimulation?
With (and without) stimulation, which protein is reacting to the treatment?
What are the differences between drugs? For now, we are ignoring the differences between treatment doses (dose are not added to the formula). This way, the model looks at the Mean effect of each drug after treatment. But, due to outliers, I am aiming to use the Median.

Overall, it is clear to me that:

Treatment duration should be regarded as confounder.
I may have outliers. See lowest dose of drug A (blue triangles) that goes above non-treated activity (gray triangles in control).
I do not have many samples to afford losing (via outlier exclusion methodologies). My only hope is to use Median instead of Mean to hopefully have a more robust estimation of the "center".


You simulated the predictor and confounder in such way that they are uncorrelated. In that case it makes no difference indeed. But what about your real data?

Also, why not run an residuals analysis and use measures like dfbeta to see if the outliers indeed are problematic?

And ... sorry fory comment in pieces ... I do not understand how subtracting the mean or median could solve a possible outliers problem. Can you explain that maybe, would be helpful.

Indeed if the confounder and predictor are correlated, I have to remove the mean/median within each groups of [predictor_level, confounder_level].
Outlier analyses is difficult, due to few samples being available. Median is not "solving" anything, its just a better estimate than the mean when we have outliers.

Thanks for the explanations and the nice graph. Do I get right that you plan to subtract the median value in the groups of predictor * confounder from the original values of Protein Activity and then run a common linear regression to estimate the predictor effects?

Yes, that is my plan.

I guess you're interested in the effect of the predictor. And this effect which is 9.99 in your example, is the difference between the two response means of the cases with predictor=1 and those with predictor=0. So you are still comparing and testing the difference between the two means not the two medians? Hence, I do not see why subtracting the group medians will change anything. If you are interested in comparing the two group medians, because these are less sensitive to outliers than the group means, you could consider to use LAV (least absolute value) regression instead of OLS.

Good remark and suggestions @BenP. Thanks! Indeed, the model would still estimate the means, so it does not matter. But LAV is a good next step to try. Please update your answer and then I set it as accepted answer.

Will do that asap. Best regards, Ben.

The response means in the levels of the confounder differ from one another when controlled for the predictor. These differences are not the same as the differences between the observed means! If you do NOT control for the predictor and simply subtract the observed means, the effect of the predictor will therefore differ from the effect found by the regression model you presented.
Only if your confounder is uncorrelated with your predictor, the effect of the predictor will be the same for both procedures. In that situation, the confounder does not really "confound" the influence of the predictor.
Further, the number of df would be different. If the confounder has 4 levels, the df in the procedure you suggest should be lowered by 3.
EDIT
Finally, I believe it will not work to subtract the median in each of the confounder groups. The interesting effect of your predictor is estimated as the difference between the two means for predictor=0 and predictor=1. So the resulting t-test for the predictor effect is in terms of means, not medians! If your really would like to work with medians, LAV or least absolute value regression could be an option, but I would not immediately choose that, see below.
If you think you may have outliers which could influence the effect of your predictor too much, I would encourage you to look at dfbeta's for your predictor variable. These would indicate if there are cases with a too high influence. The dfbeta's could show you for example that there are no or only very few influential cases about which you would have to worry, and knowing that would be great. Outliers do not necessarily cause a problem!
But in case there really are outliers with too much influence on your predictor effect, you could also consider to transform the dependent variable. For example a log transformation might work and make the outliers less influential.

Thanks @BenP, you are indeed correct that we miscalculate the degrees of freedom and as a result, the p-values.
